# 555 timer unstable pulses

Tags: clock, 555, pulse, ripple

I'm using a 555 timer to drive the clock of my circuit.
However, even with capacitors from VCC to GND, and from Pin 5 to ground, I'm still getting this "bump" when the timer transitions from HIGH to LOW (and a smaller bump from LOW to HIGH).

This (I'm guessing) causes my other IC's to sometimes trigger on the *falling edge* even though the documentation specifies a rising edge trigger. They sometimes also trigger twice on the rising edge. I've tried putting 10uF capacitors from VCC to GND on the other IC's, which alleviates the issue a bit, but after some time I'm noticing they still triggering erroneously.

I've found the error depends on the number of other chips, amount of LED's, their resistances etc. Sometimes if I hook up the oscilloscope or just put my finger somewhere it works for a bit.

I'm struggling to figure out if this is considered *normal*, if I've hooked the 555 up incorrectly, or if the problem is located somewhere else. Any tips/help is greatly appreciated!

Here's how I've hooked up the 555 timer.

[image]

Heres the falling edge when connecting to Pin 3 and GND on the 555 timer.

[image]

(The Oscilloscope reads ~400mV even though I use a 5V USB power supply. Not sure why that's the case, but my multimeter reads 5V.)

Rising edge

[image]

And here's the entire setup.

[image]

Here are the edges without a capacitor from VCC to GND. The other IC's trigger very erroneously without it.

[image]

Comment: Putting a capacitor between VCC and GND is never a solution. Those two must be kept in constant voltage difference in order for the 555 circuit to function as expected. Please give us the oscilloscope measurements before putting the 10uF capacitor in-between VCC - GND.

Comment: Furthemore check with your oscilloscope if the voltage source delivers constant voltage difference between the two breadboard VCC and GND rails.

Comment: Added a picture without the capacitor. I've read that the 555 is a power hog, and needs a capacitor to maintain a steady voltage when changing state. The voltage is stable between the rails of the breadboard.

Comment: Furthermore, I tried adding a 10nF capacitor between Pin 3 and ground to "round out" the clock edges. This actually made the edges very smooth, and made the other IC's function seemingly OK, however I'm scared to call that a "solution" since I've never seen it in any example circuits.

Comment: Could you please isolate the timer 555 circuit and measure with the oscilloscope the Pin 3 output? By isolating timer 555 circuit I mean taking the white wire away and measuring timer's OUT voltage without any interference from external circuit.

Comment: There are no bypass capacitors anywhere near the chips. I only see one ceramic capacitor as power supply bypass  at the bottom. Add a 100nF ceramic capacitor on eac chip. If you scope the supply, it might have dips at the operating frequency. Also, the dips could be on ground too, and the phemomenon is called ground bounce.

Comment: Isolating the 555 didn't do anything drastic, just a slight difference in maximum voltage.

I believe I tried adding 1uF or 10uF capacitors to the VCC - GND pins on each chip, which made it *better* but the problem just became more rare. Were the capacitors just too big?

Comment: Your supply bypass capacitors must have low ESR, like ceramics. If you used 1uF or 10uF electrolytics as bypass caps then they wouldn't have helped much.

Comment: Will investigate and try this! So you reckon it has little to do with the wonky edges of the 555?

Comment: This is what you expect building switching circuits on a breadboard. Nothing unexpected here. One simple way to start cleaning up the bouncing edges is series termination : connect the 555 output (pin 3) to everything else inc. scope via a 75 ohm resistor (right at pin 3). The other comments are correct : 0.1 uF ceramic across each chip right at the power pins.

Comment: "The Oscilloscope reads ~400mV even though I use a 5V supply. Not sure why that's the case" Are you using a x10 scope probe? (If so, have you adjusted it to show a clean square wave from the internal calibration source?) It would help to state the vertical sensitivity and horizontal time per division on the scope pictures.

Comment: Thanks guys! Added some ceramic capacitors and a small resistor, now it works much more stable :)